# Edit action with Dependency Injection ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, parameter-passing, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to make Edit action using DI.

I am using **Manage** View to Edit or Delete objects.

**IPost** interface:

```cs
using collector_forum.Data.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace collector_forum.Data
{
    public interface IPost
    {
        Post GetById(int id);
        IEnumerable<Post> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<Post> GetFilteredPosts(int id, string searchQuery);
        IEnumerable<Post> GetFilteredPosts(string searchQuery);
        IEnumerable<Post> GetPostsByCategory(int id);
        IEnumerable<Post> GetLatestPosts(int n);


        Task Add(Post post);
        Task Delete(int id);
        void Update(Post post);

        Task AddReply(PostReply reply);
    }
}
```

**PostService** Update Method:

```cs
public void Update(Post post)
        {
            _context.Posts.Update(post);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

PostController Edit GET and POST Action:

```cs
public IActionResult Edit(int postId)
        {
            Post postt = _postService.GetById(postId);
            return View(postt);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Post post)
        {
            _postService.Update(post);
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }
```

**Post** Model that **Update** and **Edit** methods refers to:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace collector_forum.Data.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<PostReply> Replies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my **Edit** View:

```html
@model collector_forum.Data.Models.Post

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Post";
}
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row sectionHeader">
        <div class="sectionHeading">New Post</div>
        <div class="sectionDescription">
            <p>
                Please read the Forum Guidelines before creating a new post.

                @if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <span>You must be a <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">registered member</a> to create a new post.</span>}
            </p>
        </div>
        @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <div class="createPost">
                <div class="row createPost">
                    <div class="createPostSection">
                        <div class="authorBlock">
                            You're submitting this post as <strong>@Model.User.UserName</strong>
                        </div>
                        <form asp-action="Edit" method="post" id="addPostForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Title"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Content"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="submitPostBtn" class="btn btn-submitPost">
                                Edit Post
                            </button>
                            <input asp-for="Category.Id" type="hidden" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ig9AkVY84bM&ab_channel=ASP.NETMVC) and can't replace postId - it's creating new ID, and can't pass non-edited values like userId/UserName.

When I confirm edited post I get NullReferenceException from Database - [errorpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MBOv.png)

And this is my table view after "changes" - [DBtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnMm4.png)

How to just edit Title and Content of this post without touching other fields?

If You need more code, let me know.

Comment: We don't know what's in your `post` variable (inside `Edit(Post post)` action and we don't know how your `_postService.Update(post)` method looks like, so it's impossible to tell what's the problem.

Comment: I just edit question and add code that you want. I've included the code for the `Update` method

Comment: @Piotr Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it on how to fix NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: @Piotr Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. The code you have provided is incomplete, as the exception comes from the `HomeController` and its view page.

Comment: @Progman Why you redirect me to another question that it is not very much related to my problem? My question is about passing or not passing specific field values. Which are declared in Model. Simple question man. I'm newbie in this technology so I 'm here to ask others

Comment: @Piotr Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402227/posting-to-edit-controller-action-not-passing-id-of-model on how to pass variables/values from your model which are not directly editable in your HTML form (like an id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass userId to `Edit` action when you post your form,so when you update `Post post`,UserId will be null.You can add hidden input with  into your form of Edit View:

```
<input asp-for="User.Id" type="hidden" />
```

So that you will have user id in `Post post` of your Edit action.And then you can save it to db.